# Beautiful soup - 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract just the text from an anchor tag. I understand that `find_all` returns a ResultSet object and that I need to iterate over it, however, I can't seem to get it work. My code below:

```
for all in soup.find("div", {"id": "info-area"}):
    Name = all.find_all("a")
    #print(Name) # Returns everything
    #print(Name.text) # throws error 
    for the_name in Name:
        print(Name.text) # throws error
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong but not quite sure what?

Comment: What are you doing? Why are you using the same loop variable for 2 loops?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - see edit

Comment: Take a second to think about why you're creating a `the_name` variable if you never use it... and what `Name` is.

Comment: @Maverick `print(Name.text)` see anything wrong with this?

Comment: @Rawing - To my understanding, I need to iterate through it to print text. This is the way I know to.

Comment: @Maverick The loop does this for you. You need `print(the_name.text)`

Comment: Ahh of course. Feeling rather silly now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first for loop, change your code to:

```
all_div = soup.find("div", {"id": "info-area"}) #find div with id = info-area
Name = all_div.find_all("a") # under all_div find all a
for the_name in Name: #loop through each a
    print(the_name.text) #print each a text
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maverick,

"Name" is the list, which has all 'a' tag elements.

You can not use .text attribute on a list.

To my understanding, the below code should work

```
for the_name in Name:
    print(the_name.text)
```

Your approach is correct. But the mistake you did in the above loop is, for each element in the list you have call the element("the_name") not the list ("Name")